# Python 2.7 yield is creating strange behavior

Tags: python, python-2.7

Using Python 2.7....

The `print thread["Subject"]` should return:

```
please ignore - test2
```

and

```
Please ignore - test
```

It does successfully with this:

```
def thread_generator(threads):
    tz = pytz.timezone('America/Chicago')
    POSTS_SINCE_HOURS = 24
    now_date = datetime.datetime.now(tz)
    time_stamp = now_date - datetime.timedelta(hours=POSTS_SINCE_HOURS)
for thread in threads:
    last_post_time = convert_time(thread["LatestPostDate"])

    if last_post_time > time_stamp:
        print thread["Subject"]
        row = {
            "url": thread["Url"],
            "author_username": thread["Author"]["Username"],
            "author_name": thread["Author"]["DisplayName"],
            "thread_id": thread["Id"],
            "forum_id": thread["ForumId"],
            "subject": thread["Subject"],
            "created_date": thread["Content"]["CreatedDate"],
            "reply_count": thread["ReplyCount"],
            "latest_post_date": thread["LatestPostDate"],
            "latest_reply_author": thread["LatestForumReplyAuthorId"] }
```

But, when adding the `yield row` the `print thread["Subject"]` does not show `Please ignore - test` as it should.

```
def thread_generator(threads):
    tz = pytz.timezone('America/Chicago')
    POSTS_SINCE_HOURS = 24
    now_date = datetime.datetime.now(tz)
    time_stamp = now_date - datetime.timedelta(hours=POSTS_SINCE_HOURS)

    for thread in threads:
        last_post_time = convert_time(thread["LatestPostDate"])

        if last_post_time > time_stamp:
            print thread["Subject"]
            row = {
                "url": thread["Url"],
                "author_username": thread["Author"]["Username"],
                "author_name": thread["Author"]["DisplayName"],
                "thread_id": thread["Id"],
                "forum_id": thread["ForumId"],
                "subject": thread["Subject"],
                "created_date": thread["Content"]["CreatedDate"],
                "reply_count": thread["ReplyCount"],
                "latest_post_date": thread["LatestPostDate"],
                "latest_reply_author": thread["LatestForumReplyAuthorId"] }
            yield row
```

Why is this? `Please ignore - test` should still show with `print thread["Subject"]`. Makes no sense to me.

**UPDATE**: How the generators is called

```
def sanitize_threads(threads):
    for thread in thread_generator(threads):
        do stuff
        thread_batch.append(thread)
     return thread_batch

def get_unanswered_threads():
    slug = 'forums/threads/unanswered.json?PageSize=100'
    status_code, threads = do_request(slug)
    if status_code == 200:
        threads = threads["Threads"]
        thread_batch = sanitize_threads(threads)
        database_update(thread_batch)
```

Comment: show how you are using `thread_generator()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried actually calling `next()` on the resultant generator? If you call the function with `yield` the same way you call the function without, in the `yield` case you'll get a generator object as a result. A generator doesn't evaluate what's inside it until you actually require a value of it, which can be done with `next(generator)`.

For example:

```
>>> def nogen():
...   '''Create a list of values 0-3 and print each one as you build the list.'''
...   r = []
...   for i in range(3):
...     print(i)
...     r.append(i)
...   return r
... 
>>> def firstgen():
...   '''Create an iterator of values 0-3 and print each one as you yield the value.'''
...   for i in range(3):
...     print(i)
...     yield i
... 
>>> a = nogen() # This function is eager and does everything at once.
0
1
2
>>> a
[0, 1, 2]
>>> b = firstgen() # Note there's no output immediately after this line.
>>> list(b) # The output happens as the list coercion causes the generator to execute.
0
1
2
[0, 1, 2]
>>> c = firstgen() # You can also see this a step at a time using `next`
>>> next(c)
0
0
>>> next(c)
1
1
>>> next(c)
2
2
>>> next(c)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

Comment: I see...the `return thread_batch` from `sanitize_threads(threads)` is keeping the generator from iterating. Why is this?

Comment: Ah...it was the indention of `return thread_batch`. I mistakenly had it in the for loop.